# AWS CLI S3 sync corrupts png images on download

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-filer

I have images successfully uploaded using django filer. I know it is a success because the images are viewable through my browser directly on the S3 storage endpoint.

When I try and sync the uploaded files to a different desktop the images are 1kb larger and corrupted.

Any ideas to solve this issue?

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://$AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME/media/filer_public/4e/79/4e7929c1-e7fa-4f39-80c8-0c958efac0d0/ .
download: s3://viatu-staging-test/media/filer_public/4e/79/4e7929c1-e7fa-4f39-80c8-0c958efac0d0/giraffe-cover-image_7.png to ./giraffe-cover-image_7.png
$ _
```

Downloaded from browser

```
$ wc -c giraffe1.png 
1542520 giraffe1.png
```

Downloaded with AWS S3 CLI and corrupted

```
$ wc -c giraffe-cover-image_7.png 
1543013 giraffe-cover-image_7.png
```

Comment: How is it corrupted? You mean the S3 image is corrupted or your local copy? What is the problem?

Comment: Trying to open the local downloaded S3 file and it is an Unrecognised image file format

Comment: So aws s3 sync is not downloading the file correctly is your issue?

Comment: What is the exact output of s3 sync? Are the files encrypted by any key?

Comment: After some more investigation it seems like only png's are affected. If I upload jpg's and use s3 sync then I do not get any corruption and the image size remains the same. I added the exact output of s3 sync and I am not encrypting the files

Comment: try with a random png off the internet